# How to find the difference of ratio in multiple columns using R

Tags: r, diff

I have data frame with 4 different years with values. I need to find how these values changes in all years i.e which city changes its value too often which is least.

```
City     Ratio1     Ratio2     Ratio3     Ratio4
A        1.0177722  1.0173251  1.0133026  1.0140027
B        1.0132619  1.0122653  1.0128473  1.0111068
C        1.0689484  1.0640355  1.0625305  1.0544790

..... other 1000 entries
```

I have tried to do it by difference but no luck. The question is which city's ratio changed most between ratio1 to ratio4 and which is least changed.
I have tried using mutate function to calculate variance but it throws me an warning:

```
DF<- DF%>% mutate(vari = var(Ratio1:Ratio4,na.rm = T))

Warning messages:
1: In POP_2013_ratio:POP_2016_ratio :
  numerical expression has 439 elements: only the first used
2: In POP_2013_ratio:POP_2016_ratio :
  numerical expression has 439 elements: only the first used
```

Comment: If you're interested in the changes among the four observations, you can just calculate the variances/standard deviation among the four ratios. If you're just interested in the absolute changes, you can calculate the ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R's data.table package has a pretty neat way to create new columns based on existing ones:

```
dt <- data.table(City = c("A", "B", "C"),
                 Ratio1 = c(1.0177722, 1.0132619, 1.0689484),
                 Ratio2 = c(1.0173251, 1.0122653, 1.0640355), 
                 Ratio3 = c(1.0133026, 1.0128473, 1.0625305), 
                 Ratio4 = c(1.0140027,1.0111068, 1.0544790))
>dt 
   City   Ratio1   Ratio2   Ratio3   Ratio4
1:    A 1.017772 1.017325 1.013303 1.014003
2:    B 1.013262 1.012265 1.012847 1.011107
3:    C 1.068948 1.064035 1.062531 1.054479
```

You can play around with some functions and then see what suits you best:

```
 dt[, diff := Ratio4-Ratio1
    ][, abs_diff := abs(Ratio4-Ratio1)
      ][, range:= max(c(Ratio1, Ratio2, Ratio3, Ratio4))-  min(c(Ratio1, Ratio2, Ratio3, Ratio4)), by = City
        ][,variance:=var(c(Ratio1, Ratio2, Ratio3, Ratio4)), by = City]

 >dt

    City   Ratio1   Ratio2   Ratio3   Ratio4       diff  abs_diff     range     variance
 1:    A 1.017772 1.017325 1.013303 1.014003 -0.0037695 0.0037695 0.0044696 5.174612e-06
 2:    B 1.013262 1.012265 1.012847 1.011107 -0.0021551 0.0021551 0.0021551 8.766456e-07
 3:    C 1.068948 1.064035 1.062531 1.054479 -0.0144694 0.0144694 0.0144694 3.609233e-05
```

When you're finally decided on the criteria to use (let's say, variance), you can select the top City using:

```
dt[order(-variance)][1]

>dt
   City   Ratio1   Ratio2   Ratio3   Ratio4       diff  abs_diff     range     variance
1:    C 1.068948 1.064035 1.062531 1.054479 -0.0144694 0.0144694 0.0144694 3.609233e-05
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I have applied variance formula but got some issues in my mutate function. Updated in my question.